# Oracle Forms Print Execute Query

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have an Oracle form which has EXECUTE_QUERY(NO_VALIDATE) in the KEY_EXEQUERY trigger.

I would like to see the what is the query been executed, how can I print the sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Pre-Query trigger get the SYSTEM.LAST_QUERY value to get the text of the query.

Comment: if you use pre-query you have to query again to see the last query. Better make a button or so.